# Retrieve the owner of a polymorphic relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I'm trying to retrieve the owner of an Eloquent polymorphic relationship I defined in my app. Here is the relation : a `Theme` can be posted either by a `Enseignant` or a `Partenaire` , so both can post themes. Here are the models and the polymorphic relationship corresponding :

`Theme` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Theme extends Model
{

    public function themePoster(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`Enseignant` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Enseignant extends Model
{


    public function utilisateur(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Utilisateur');
    }

    public function themes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Theme', 'themePoster');
    }
}
```

`Partenaire` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Partenaire extends Model
{


    public function utilisateur(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Utilisateur');
    }

    public function themes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Theme', 'themePoster');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the owner of a `theme` in my blade view as the way showed in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Here is the Controller `show` function :

```
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $theme = Theme::findOrFail($id);
        return view('themeShow', ['theme' => $theme]);
    }
```

`themeShow` blade view

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<body>
{{$theme->intitule}} <br>
{{$theme->categorie}} <br>
{{$theme->filiereDesiree}} <br>
{{$theme->description}} <br>
<a href=" {{url('themes')}} "><button>Voir tous</button></a>
@if(Auth::guard('web')->user()->hasRole('etudiant'))
<a href=""><button>Choisir thématique</button></a>
Proposé par {{ $theme->themePoster }}
@elseif(Auth::guard('web')->user()->id == $theme->themePoster_id)
<a href=" {{ url('themes/' .$theme->id. '/edit' ) }} "><button>Modifier thématique</button></a>
<form method="POST" action=" {{ route('themes.destroy', $theme->id ) }} ">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
<a class="btn btn-danger"> <input  class="delete" type="submit" name="submit" value="Supprimer thématique"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
</form>
@endif
@jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(){
        return confirm('Etes-vous sûr de vouloir de supprimer cette thématique?');
    });
</script>
</body>
@endsection
```

So here is the line supposed to retrieve the owner of the theme:

```
Proposé par {{ $theme->themePoster }}
```

Yet I'm not getting anything: `Proposé par`: nothing is returned. What am I missing there..? I'm pretty new at Laravel for this being my first app and first time using polymorphic relationships. Your help would be very welcome

**Edit**

As the information may be useful for more comprehension.. here is my database structure:

`Utilisateurs` table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUtilisateursTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('utilisateurs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('fonction');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('utilisateurs');
    }
}
```

Note : `Enseignant` and `Partenaire` inherits `Utilisateur`.

`Utilisateur`'s model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Utilisateur extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'utilisateurs';

    public function hasRole($role){
        return $this->fonction == $role;
    }

    public function etudiants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Etudiant');
    }

    public function enseignants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Enseignant');
    }

    public function partenaires(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Partenaire');
    }
}
```

`Enseignants` table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEnseignantsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('enseignants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('utilisateur_id')->unique();
            $table->string('isAdmin');
            $table->string('nomEntreprise')->nullable();
            $table->string('descEntreprise')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('enseignants');
    }
}
```

`Partenaires` table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePartenairesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('partenaires', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('utilisateur_id')->unique();
            $table->string('structure');
            $table->string('description_structure');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('partenaires');
    }
}
```

Basically, `themePoster_id` and `themePoster_type` are created by getting the current `Enseignant` or `Partenaire` id and fonction.  Here's the code responsible of getting those attributes:

```
<input type="hidden" id="themePoster_id" name="themePoster_id" value= "{{Auth::guard('web')->user()->id}}">
<input type="hidden" id="themePoster_type" name="themePoster_type" value= "{{Auth::guard('web')->user()->fonction}}">
```

and as you can see here in this sample of  [theme table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cG8Z.png), it is well recorded but I'm getting issue with this `{{ $theme->themePoster }}` which returns nothing here.

Comment: Welcome to Laravel! Firstly, can you tell a little more about your database structure? Secondly, confirm if `$theme->themePoster_id` and `$theme->themePoster_type` have values. Thirdly `{{ $theme->themePoster }}` will output an object, usually not something that should be outputted as a string.

Comment: Thanks!:) . I've edited the question so you may have a clearer understanding of what I'm trying to do. For the ```{{ $theme->themePoster }}```, I tried as it's said in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations), like the same logic they use in it I think.. or what should I normally do to retrieve it then..?

Comment: A thing that stands out is the use of `user()->id` and `user()->fonction` as your morph class. It is not incorrect but above you state " a Theme can be posted either by a `Enseignant` or a `Partenaire`" not `User`. The other thing, and I think this is why it cannot find anything, is the use of the wrong `themePoster_id` and `themePoster_class`. I will post an answer later today, if no one has done it already.

Comment: For the `user()->id` and `user()->fonction` part, I've ensured with a middleware that the logged user which can access the `themeCreate` view is either a `Enseignant` or  a `Partenaire` and it's working fine. Thank you to have it remarked though

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) we (by default) need the following:

- The proper database columns.
- The proper relationship declarations.

In your case this would be the following:

```
// Themes table:
$table->morphs('themePoster');

// Which is short for:
$table->string('themePoster_type');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('themePoster_id');


// Partenaire and Enseignant models:
public function themes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Theme', 'themePoster');
}

// Theme model:
public function themePoster(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

([Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1202)) of `morphs`.

Relating a polymorphable model could be done this way:

```
$partenaire->themes()->create([
    ...
]);

// The default behavior will result in this theme db record:
 themePoster_type | themePoster_id | more columns here 
 -----------------|----------------|-------------------
 'App\Partenaire' | 1              | ...
```

The part where I think it is going wrong in your code would be the value of the `themePoster_type`. An assumption is that your record will look like this:

```
themePoster_type | themePoster_id | more columns here 
 -----------------|----------------|-------------------
 'partenaire'     | 1              | ...
```

Laravel cannot find `partenaire` as a model, so it does not know in which table it should look. My assumption would be Laravel throwing an exception, but I might be wrong.

In short I think the `input` with `Auth::guard('web')->user()->fonction` sends the incorrect value. In your case it should be `App\Partenaire` or `App\Enseignant`.

Laravel [provides](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types) a solution to map certain strings to the correct classes. This would be a nice solution if the problem I am stating is correct. You can map the keys to the correct classes. This would result in:

```
// AppServiceProvider@boot
Relation::morphMap([
    'partenaire' => 'App\Partenaire',
    'enseignant' => 'App\Enseignant',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I get better why it appears to not work. I've just tried your solution, still got the same issue, nothing returned

Comment: I get it certainly have something with how I register the `themePoster_type` and `themePoster_id` values.. but how may I here register them, I mean so they will be known by Laravel to be either `App\Enseignant` or `App\Partenaire` instance attributes. As I told it above.. I just get the current logged user `id` and `fonction` and as ones who may access to that view are either `Enseignant` or `Partenaire` it takes then those respective attributes value according to that type of user